# How to add child element in soap header in java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, spring

How to add child element in soap header in java spring webservice.

I have tried two approach but nothing is working please suggest me what need to be done?

first approach :-

```
soapHeaderString.append("<tem:Culture>en_Us</tem:Culture><tem:AgentCode>PumpkinSafari</tem:AgentCode><tem:PartnerID></tem:PartnerID><tem:Password>PMP22#in</tem:Password>");

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
// Here we create a Source Tree
StringSource stringSource = new StringSource(soapHeaderString.toString());
transformer.transform(stringSource, soapHeader.getResult());
```

but it is giving me error

```
The prefix "tem" for element "tem:Culture" is not bound.
```

2nd Approach :-

```
SoapHeaderElement headerElement=soapMessage.getSoapHeader().addHeaderElement(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "SOAPHeaderAuth","tem"));
headerElement.setText(soapHeaderString.toString());
```

It produce unescaped sequqnce so service provider give error as it was not able to understand the request.

Please help me what need to be  done to solve the problem.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, in my case too it prompts the same error, The prefix "username" for element "wsse:username" is not bound. I tried doing everything to add namespace declaration. But, it doesn't worked!

"Finally", I was able to do it last night with a workaround, converting some way from Spring `org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapHeader` to `javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader`. And no issues now!

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = ((SaajSoapMessage) message).getSaajMessage();
SOAPHeader header = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();
SOAPHeaderElement security = header.addHeaderElement(new QName(SCHEMA, "Security", SCHEMA_PREFIX));
SOAPElement usernameToken = security.addChildElement("UsernameToken", SCHEMA_PREFIX);
SOAPElement usernameElement = usernameToken.addChildElement("Username", SCHEMA_PREFIX);
SOAPElement passwordElement = usernameToken.addChildElement("Password", SCHEMA_PREFIX);

usernameElement.setTextContent(username);
passwordElement.setTextContent(password);
```

Through this I was able to add namespace declarations to spring soap header child elements!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simple and it works.

Answer (score 3):

**JAX-WS Users**

I would recommend using a message handler:

http://www.javadb.com/using-a-message-handler-to-alter-the-soap-header-in-a-web-service-client

**Spring Web Services Users**

A similar concept exists:

http://arcanetechnotes.blogspot.com/2008/12/modifying-soap-headers-with-spring-web.html

The question states that it cannot understand the `tem` namespace, so perhaps register the namespace in the header:

```
soapHeader.addNamespaceDeclaration("tem", "http://whatever.namespace.com/");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Can i use this handle with spring WS as i am using websericegatwaysupport class

Comment: I don't think it will work with spring can you please help me

Comment: Try your first approach from your question, just make sure the namespace is added.

Comment: i have tried adding soapHeader.addNamespaceDeclaration("tem", "http://whatever.namespace.com/"); but it doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work how?  Does it still say `The prefix "tem" for element "tem:Culture" is not bound.`?

Comment: Any solutions! I am facing the same problem too.. soapHeader.addNamespaceDeclaration(..) doesn't solve the purpose

Comment: @RohitBansal What is the specific error that you're getting?

Comment: Posted the solution, could finally work it out after long searching almost everything!

Answer (score 0):

Use "header=true" property  in webparam 
Like

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "someMethod")
    public String someMethod(@WebParam(name = "yourBeanObj") YourBeanObjClass yourBeanObj,
            @WebParam(header = true, mode = WebParam.Mode.IN, name = "username") String userName,
            @WebParam(header = true, mode = WebParam.Mode.IN, name = "password") String pwd) {
//todo stuff
}
```

As per above example "yourBeanObj" wil be added into soap body, "username" and "password" are add in soap header.