# SoapHeaderElement child?

Tags: java, spring, soap, soapheader

Is there a way to nest/add child elements to SoapHeaderElement? I have looked around to no avail. Need to add a security soap header with the standard Security, UsernameToken, Username and Password.

Similar posts I have looked at:

[Add child elements to custom SOAP header in Spring-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035423/add-child-elements-to-custom-soap-header-in-spring-ws/4186230)

[How to add child element in soap header in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322634/how-to-add-child-element-in-soap-header-in-java)

What I need to add to the SOAP envelope:

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="">
            <wsse:Username></wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"></wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I have tried casting to SOAPHeaderElement instead, since that actually has an addChild method, but get a casting error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapHeaderElement cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeaderElement
```

Any fix to this casting error or workaround otherwise?

Comment: Assuming you are using Spring-WS you should be configuring the security interceptor correctly and these will be added automatically. You shouldn't be manually messing around with adding headers in general.

Comment: Configured a Wss4jSecurityInterceptor to handle the additional security headers. Much more clean cut than manual entries. Thanks.